# Cannot reach to the href in a html element -Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to randomize a wikipedia page and get the URL of that randomized site. Even though I can fetch every link on the site, I can not reach to this piece of html code and fetch the `href` for some reason.
An example of a randomized wikipedia page.

```html
<a accesskey="v" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%99eb%C3%ADvlice?action=edit" class="oo-ui-element-hidden"></a>
```

All the wikipedia pages have this and I need to get the `href` so that I can manipulate this in a way that I can get the current URL.
The code I have written this far:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
links = []
for x in range(0, 1):
    source = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    print(soup.find(id="firstHeading"))
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    print(links)
```

Directly getting the current URL would also help too, however I couldn't find a solution for that online.
Also I'm using Lunix OS -if that would help-

Comment: Help us to help you - Please, show up your code and improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Take a look for the attributes

You should specify your search by using the attribute of this `<a>`:

```
soup.find_all('a', accesskey='e')
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
links = []
for x in range(0, 1):
    source = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    print(soup.find(id="firstHeading"))
    for link in soup.find_all('a', accesskey='e'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    print(links)
```

**Output**

```
<h1 class="firstHeading" id="firstHeading" lang="en">James Stack (golfer)</h1>
['/w/index.php?title=James_Stack_(golfer)&action=edit']
```

---

### Just in case

You do not need the second loop, if you just wanna handle that single `<a>` use `find()` instead of `find_all()`

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
links = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    source = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    links.append(soup.find('a', accesskey='e').get('href'))

links
```

**Output**

```
['/w/index.php?title=Rick_Moffat&action=edit',
 '/w/index.php?title=Mount_Burrows&action=edit',
 '/w/index.php?title=The_Rock_Peter_and_the_Wolf&action=edit',
 '/w/index.php?title=Yamato,_Yamanashi&action=edit',
 '/w/index.php?title=Craig_Henderson&action=edit']
```

Comment: Oh, and then I can get the titles and then prefix them with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ in order to get the URL of their sites. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help - Yeah, that is the way you can go!